# Array of Integers Comparing Integers VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Basically I have and array of integers that vary in size. I need to compare each number to each other number and display which number is repeated. For example:

```
Dim ints() As Integer = {1,2,2,5,4,6}
```

The number that shows up more than once is 2.

How can I run through the array and compare each integer with the numbers in the array. I tried a for loop but it didn't return the value I was looking for. I am new to VB.NET and do not understand fully.

Comment: Can you add your for loop? We might then be able to provide hints on what's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ints() As Integer = {1,2,2,5,4,6}

Dim repeatedNumbers = ints.GroupBy(Function(intValue) intValue) _
                          .Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1)

For each grp in repeatedNumbers
    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} is repeated {1} times", grp(0), grp.Count)
Next
```

What this code does:

- We first call GroupBy, which groups items by their value. The Function gets the grouping key, in this case we simply group by the array's value itself. This call returns a sequence of
  groups. There is one group for every unique value in the array. The
  group contains all items that correspond to a unique value. So if a value appears twice in the array, there will be a group which contains two ints with this value.
- We call Where to filter groups. We only want groups for which the count is greater than one, so that only duplicate values are considered.
- We then loop through the result. grp(0) gives us the first number in the group (we could have picked any number in the group, since all numbers in a group are the same!) and the Count property gives us the number of repetitions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this solution worked the best. My question is what is `Function(x)` and `Function(grp)` I just want to make sure I fully understand how I am getting what I am getting.

Comment: They are lambda expressions and are commonly used with Linq functions like GroupBy and Where. Check the following MSDN link for lambda expressions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: I also edited the answer to try to explain what the code does. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with something like this:

```
    Dim ints() As Integer = {1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 6}
    Array.Sort(ints)
    For i = 1 To ints.GetUpperBound(0)
        If ints(i) = ints(i - 1) Then MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} is repeated", ints(i)))
    Next
```

Doing it like this on a sorted array keeps down the nesting.

I've not tested this but it should be along the right lines.

Comment: Not a bad solution but if a number appears more than twice, you will see two messages or more for that number.

Comment: I went for simple to get things started, but yes you're right, it could be more subtle.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397910.aspx) to find the duplicates:

```
Dim repeating = (From n In ints
                 Group By n Into Dups = Group
                 Where Dups.Count > 1
                 Select Dups.First).ToArray()
```

This returns an Array of integers which only contains numbers that are not unique in the original array.

So this displays the repeating number(s):

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Duplicates found: {0}", String.Join(","c, repeating)))
```